# Python Dataframe dynamically offset value/calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two column dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date          Value
1990-11-27    1
1990-11-28    2
1990-11-29    3
1990-11-30    4
1990-12-01    5
...           ...
```

And I'm trying to do some simple calculations by referencing prior values based on some lookback period, such as last day, last month, last year, x years, etc

To get the prior value I'm looking for I thought I'd try to use an `apply` based on some timeseries offset I could pass in, but instead of a single column, it seems to populate a new column for each value using the following:

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda row: df[df['Date'] == row - pd.tseries.offset.MonthEnd()]['Value'])
```

Is there any way to get the results all in a single series? I tried the dataframe `apply` as well and set `axis=1` but was still seeing the same result. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `merge`

```
df1=df.copy()
df1['Date']=df1['Date'] - MonthEnd()
df_merged=df.merge(df1,on='Date',how='left')
        Date  Value_x  Value_y
0 1990-11-27        1      NaN
1 1990-11-28        2      NaN
2 1990-11-29        3      NaN
3 1990-11-30        4      5.0
4 1990-12-01        5      NaN
```

Comment: Hm, I would still need to get the values for the non month ends to link back to the prior eom as well, maybe if I did a `ffill()` after the `-MonthEnd()`?